# Microsoft Office (ofice 2021) MSFT Activation Key - using on future PC builds

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-activation

If I purchased a developer intended Office 2021 key from a reseller (obviously not meant to be resold), and use it on one PC it works fine. If I rebuild the OS the activation system sees this rebuild as a new PC, and after one or two rebuilds will not allow activation.

Any methods to get around this?

Comment: if you are entitled to the license, contact support. if you are not, we're not going to help you. MS will often help you with OEM license issues after a PC repair like a motherboard replacement, but they won;t do it ad-infinitum.

Comment: There is no reason to often reset Windows. There are other solutions to such problems.

Comment: Find a student that doesn't use Office. Get the education discount.

Comment: I agree with Frank Thomas, so can you try Microsoft 365 apps? Generally one license account can signed on 5 machines, and you can also deactivate license.